# OpenLayers: Properly use a WMS layer to display a TMS layer from a different server

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, tile-map-service

I have two servers:

the first server is 177 and that has a html file with the TMS layer.

We will call this tms_layer.html and it has your init function with this in there:

```
var tmsoverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS Overlay", "",
  {
    serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.', alpha: true, type: 'JPG', getURL:   
    overlay_getTileURL, isBaseLayer: true
  });
```

When i go to 177/tms_layer.html the tiles are being correctly displayed.

So that is working fine.

**Now, I want to serve that tms_layer.html file on a different server (server 190)**, and I have been trying to serve it as a WMS layer. Not sure if WMS is the best approach but I think it is. Correct me if I'm wrong.

We'll call this tiles_revision1.html and within the init function I currently have:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "My TMS layer in WMS",
  "http://177/dev/tiles/tiles_1a.html", {layers: ['tmsoverlay'], transparent: "true", format: "image/jpg"} );
map.addLayer(layer);
```

For the `layers: []` do I even need to reference this since it's just a bunch of jpgs making up the tile(s)/map? Leaving it blank has not done anything.

With the above code I currently get a blank OL map, see here (When I pan around the map I get a Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'wrapDateLine' of null. I don't think that is the root of my issue though):

[image]

**Edit**: the most important thing here is to be able to access those 177 tiles from anywhere as a baselayer. There is quite a few associated jpgs, and the `tms_layer.html` file is pretty beefy on its own.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you want to access the tile Cache as an WMS Layer. It won't work without an actual WMS service running on the `117` server. What you need to do is to access it as an TMS layer from the new server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Devdatta Tengshe suggested, you have to configure a TMS layer in tiles_revision1.html.

```
var tmsoverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( 
    "TMS Overlay", 
    "http://url_to_177/",
    {
        serviceVersion: '.', 
        layername: '.', 
        alpha: true, 
        type: 'JPG', 
        getURL: overlay_getTileURL, 
        isBaseLayer: true
    });
```

If you still want (or need) to access the tiles via a WMS, you will have to setup a WMS service. If that so, look for one of these:

- [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/)
- [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome)
- [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is the js function `overlay_getTileURL` is defined within `tiles_1a.html` on 177 and there's some other somewhat lengthy javascript defined in that file. How do I accommodate for that, as I don't want to be repeating myself everytime?

Comment: You will need to take the javascript out of the html file and put it in a `.js` file. Then you will include this javascript file in `tiles_1a.html` and `tiles_revision1.html` like this: `<script src="http://url_to_177/your_js_file.js"></script>`